# How to speed up a function going through multiple sets of parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Supposed you have a function of this type, and some data = df:

```
function_(df, parameter_a, parameter_b, parameter_c)
```

The parameters are themselves lists of elements (strings, datetime objects). And result_ is a small dataframe, 1 column x 25 rows max.

```
result_ = function_(df, [a, b, c], [d, f], [x, y, c])
%timeit result_
10000000 loops, best of 3: 37.5 ns per loop
```

Supposed you have at least 1000 sets of parameters to run your function, right now they are stored like this:

```
parameter_sets = [('set_1', function_(df, [a, b, c], [d, f], [x, y, c])),
                  ('set_2', function_(df, [b, c, d], [a, b], [x, x, x])),
                   ...
                   ...
                  ('set_1000', function_(df, [b, b, d], [b, b], [x, y, y]))]
```

If I want to run all the parameters sets and consolidate the results of each output, I do something like this:

```
def run1000_function():
    parameter_sets = [('set_1', function_(df, [a, b, c], [d, f], [x, y, c])),
                      ('set_2', function_(df, [b, c, d], [a, b], [x, x, x])),
                       ...
                       ...
                      ('set_1000', function_(df, [b, b, d], [b, b], [x, y, y]))]

    output_d = dict(parameter_sets) #probably unnecessary, but used for convinience
    for key, df in output_d.items():
        df['Name'] = key  #to associate the set name with the output

    final_result = pd.concat(parameter_sets.values(), axis=0)

    return final result
```

All this works perfectly as intended, but the issue is that is taking too much time. When I run run1000_function(), It takes more than 20 minutes. It appears that is the running the list 'parameter_sets' that is problematic. The question is how can I store and read these sets of parameters so I speed up this whole process?

Comment: Where is your `function_` call for the `parameter_sets`?

Comment: @randomir No, function_  runs only in a single parameter set.

Comment: The "I do something like this" code doesn't make sense. The dict seems to be unnecessary, you keep assigning things to `df['name']`, and then the `final_result` doesn't involve anything you just did. Also, `parameter_sets` shouldn't have a `values`. Can you replace that with code that makes sense?

Comment: What part of the code is taking a long time? Is it the construction of `parameter_sets`, which involves running `function_` a thousand times? Or is it `pd.concat`? Also, do you hardcode the parameters for each call to `function_` or are you generating those in some code you haven't posted?

Comment: @wkschwartz Yes is the parameters_sets running that takes the whole time. Yes the parameters are harcoded for each call to function_

Comment: @user2357112 The df['Name'] thing is just to associate each key with each output of function_. See the edit I did for clarity.

Comment: Is `function_` without any arguments that's fast, or with a full `df` and set of parameters?  Usually the big time consumer is running the function many times, not the iteration and collection mechanism.

Comment: @hpaulj function_ with arguments is that fast. But it appears that running it many times, the way I do it is making it very slow.

Comment: How big are the resulting dataframes? Perhaps you are running into a memory issue as you create all 1000 of them and start using swap space (significantly increasing the processing time).

Comment: @Gavin they are not that big 1 column and max 25 rows